# Overriding Base Class abstract methods and hiding them in derived classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

I have two two types of base class;

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract object Work();
}

public abstract class AuthenticatedBase : Base
{
    public abstract object Work(T request);
}
```

The authenticated class does some extra work to check a login beforehand. Then I have different classes extending from both base classes;

```
public class A : Base
{
    public override object Work()
    {
        // Work here
    }
}

public class B : AuthenticatedBase
{
    public override object Work(T request)
    {
        // Work here
    }
}
```

Basically, when I create a new class B that derives from AuthenticatedBase, Visual Studio says I need to implement Work() from the Base class even though I have an alternate implementation in AuthenticatedBase that I am overriding, admittedly with different parameters. What should I be doing so that I don't have to implement the Work() method from the base class in inherited classes?

Comment: If it doesn't make sense to implement `Work()` in subclasses of `AuthenticatedBase` then your hierarchy needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement it, there is no way around it. This is the case where multiple inheritance would come in handy.

You could use composition so that `B` has a reference to an `A`. Then `B.Work()` can call `A.Work()`.

Alternatively, implement `B.Work()` so that it calls `B.Work(T)`. Or even have `Base.Work()` be a virtual method with the base implementation from `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the parameterless Work method in your AuthenticatedBase and use the "sealed" keyword to stop it from showing on inheritors of AuthenticatedBase.